# Hanging template for Large Minifig Case

Tags: minifigures, size

I've been happy to see LEGO came out with a way to display the *myriad* of minifigs out there:

[image: minifig case]

And I was also very happy to find that I can hang these on the wall with the convenient eyelets on the back:

[image: back of case]

Yet despite earnestly searching I can't find anybody that has created a template for installing these.  How far should the screws be apart?  How far apart should the holes be if you want stack them like so:?

[image: stacked cases]

I'd prefer a printable template that I could drill through, but if you have measured these accurately that'd be a good start.

Comment: You could easily photocopy the back side of such a case and use the copy as a template, just like in this post: http://www.element14.com/community/thread/44326/l/photocopy-as-a-drill-template

Answer (score 4):

Since no answers were given for two days, I'll convert my comment to a full answer:

If you haven't found anything yet but have access to a photocopier, you could try making a copy of the back side that contains the eyelets. The resulting print will be a 1:1 paper version of the back side, which you can tape on the wall intended for hanging the cases and drill through the images of the eyelets: [image: example demonstration using a power strip]

Be sure to align the sheet correctly, using a bubble level or such.